# Upload picture taken with phone via php/ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, ftp

I have an image which when clicked triggers a file input

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="Selector">
<img onClick="document.getElementById('Selector').click()" id="camera" />
```

After taking the picture,I then take the file and give it a temp url

```
var takePicture = document.getElementById("Selector");
takePicture.onchange = function (event) {

     var files = event.target.files,file;

     if (files && files.length > 0) {
        file = files[0];
     }

    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

I can take that temp url and set it as the src for any other image on the page and it shows up fine. Now I want to upload that image to a server. Using AJAX I send the temp URL over to a php script thats supposed to FTP the image over to the server. The file shows up on the server but is a fraction of the size its supposed to be and will not open. The PHP command I am using is:`ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)` where $file is the temp url. How screwed up is this method and is it even possible?